# How could I get ielm to evaluate a function at the last point I was in the previous buffer?

Tags: point, repl, ielm

I tried different combinations of `save-excursion` or `ielm-change-working-buffer`, but no success. I'm currently trying to see if there's a way to save a point in a buffer (using registers?) and run a function in IELM as if it was at that point.

Would anyone have suggestions on how I can make this work?

Comment: To move point, simply use `goto-char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you have a buffer, say "foo.bar", with `point` in that buffer at some position, say 23, and you have saved that position in a register, say register `a`, with `C-x r <SPACE> a RET`. If you do `M-x get-register RET a RET` you verify that register `a` contains `#<marker at 23 in foo.bar>`.

Now you go into `ielm`: `M-x ielm` . First verify that `ielm` knows about register `a`:

```el
ELISP> (get-register ?a)
#<marker at 23 in foo.bar>
```

A [marker](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Markers.html) is a position in a buffer. You can get the buffer out of the marker with `marker-buffer` and the position with `marker-position`. So we can make the marker buffer current temporarily, go to the marker position and evaluate any function we want there:

```el
ELISP> (let ((m (get-register ?a)))
          (with-current-buffer (marker-buffer m)
            (goto-char (marker-position m))
            (format "point: %d, buffer: %S" (point) (current-buffer))))
"point: 23, buffer: #<buffer foo.bar>"

ELISP> (current-buffer)
#<buffer *ielm*>
```

In this case, it's a `format` call with the value of `point` and the current buffer  as arguments to verify that we are indeed where we think we are. Instead of `format`, you can run whatever function you want. Then we are back in the `ielm` buffer after `with-current-buffer` is done.

You can of course package the boilerplate in a function:

```el
(defun ielm-run-at-register (register func &rest args)
  (let ((m (get-register register)))
    (with-current-buffer (marker-buffer m)
      (goto-char (marker-position m))
      (apply func args))))

(defun foo ()
  (format "point: %d, buffer: %S" (point) (current-buffer)))
```

and then the invocation in `ielm` becomes:

```el
ELISP> (ielm-run-at-register ?a 'foo)
"point: 23, buffer: #<buffer foo.bar>"
```

Answer (score 1):

I can not find any hook that gets triggered before a buffer change. Therefore this solution updates a buffer-local `last-buffer-position` via the `post-command-hook`.

```lisp
(defvar-local last-buffer-position nil)

(defun update-last-buffer-position ()
  (setq last-buffer-position (point)))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook #'update-last-buffer-position)

(defun ielm-eval-at-point-last-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((sexp (with-current-buffer (seq-find (lambda (b)
                                               (not (minibufferp b)))
                                             (cdr (buffer-list)))
                (goto-char last-buffer-position)
                (or (thing-at-point 'line) (thing-at-point 'sexp)))))
    (insert sexp)
    (ielm-return)))
```

To find the previous buffer, it simply searches the `buffer-list` for the first 'non-minibuffer' that is not the current buffer.

I am not sure how you would define 'function at point', I guess you mean some kind of 'sexp'. Here I chose to first look for a list at point and otherwise a sexp. You can call the command in ielm using `M-x ielm-eval-at-point-last-buffer`.